# LTSpice error when simulating behavioural voltages

Tags: ltspice, spice

I've been receiving this error whenever I want to create a voltage source affected by another voltage source:
[image]

It says here that V1 is an unknown symbol but clearly I've inserted a voltage source V1 in the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V1 is a symbol instance. You need to use the voltage of a node in your behavioural expression.

It's not clear without digging around at the schematic what LTSpice will have called the node on the top of your V1 symbol. It's best to label it manually. Use the \$\boxed{\text{A}}\$ tool on the toolbar to add a label to the relevant node.

Your equation should be V=0.0487*V(NodeLabel)+0.838

Comment: Praise you and your big help <3